# O que significa " Sou mesmo uma boba"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

O que significa " Sou mesmo uma boba"

Pode ser "Sou como uma boba"?

Comment: Possível tradução para o inglês: "I really am a fool".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não. *Bobo* significa *pateta*, *tonto*, *estúpido*. Está aqui a ser usado como nome, mas também pode ser usado como adjetivo (tal como os três sinónimos que dei). *Mesmo* é aqui advérbio com o significado de *realmente*, *de facto*:

> Não te menti, sou mesmo uma boba.

Dependendo do contexto, *mesmo* pode servir mais como intensificador:

> O que fiz foi tão estúpido — sou mesmo uma boba.

Answer (score 3):

O advérbio "mesmo" nessa frase funciona como confirmação do estado de ser boba.

A pessoa passou de um momento de dúvida (Sou uma boba?) para um momento de certeza (Sou mesmo uma boba.).